# $1+1D$ $U(1)$ gauge theory is a quantum mechanical system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, gauge-theory

In article [Exotic Symmetries, Duality, and Fractons in 2+1-Dimensional Quantum Field Theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.10466) there is statement (page 13):

> Ordinary $1 + 1$-dimensional $U(1)$ gauge theory is effectively a quantum mechanical system of a single variable.

Such theory is defined as:

$$
L = -\frac{1}{4} F^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu}
$$

In Lorentz gauge:
$$
\partial_\mu A^\mu = 0
$$

Residual freedom:

$$
A_\mu \to A_\mu +\partial_\mu \alpha 
$$
with $\Box \alpha = 0$.

Using this freedom on can remove all d.o.f. So 2d Maxwell theory haven't physical d.o.f. In colour of such consideration, this statement looks quite strange.

Could somebody explain **how to prove/check this statement?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The E&M Hamiltonian Lagrangian density without matter in 1+1D is$^1$
   $${\cal L}_H~=~-E_1 \dot{A}_1 ~-~{\cal H}_0 ~-~ A_0 \underbrace{\partial_1 E_1}_{\text{ Gauss law}}, \tag{i} $$
   where the Hamiltonian density is
   $${\cal H}_0~=~\frac{1}{2} E_1^2 -\theta E_1. \tag{ii}$$
2. Next if we use the Coulomb gauge $\partial_1 A_1=0$ together with Gauss law $\partial_1 E_1=0$, we see that the canonical field pair $(A_1,E_1)$ does not depend on space $x^1$, only on time $t$.
3. After eliminating the Lagrange multiplier field $A_0$, the field theory model (i) effectively becomes a point mechanical model with a single canonical pair $(A_1(t),E_1(t))$. This fact answers OP's title question.

--

$^1$ Eq. (i) is before gauge-fixing & after possibly ignoring spatial boundary terms. We use a Minkowski metric with positive spatial component and negative temporal component. The momentum variable to $A_1$ is *minus* $E_1$.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe there is a more vivid and rigorous argument in the continuum theory, but I am not aware of them, so I 'll present an argument from lattice gauge theory.

The discrete version of gauge theory, which in continuum limit gives ordinary Maxwell (Yang-Mills action) is so called *Wilson action*:
$$
S_G = \sum_{\Box} \beta \ (1 - \frac{1}{N_c}\text{Tr } U_{\Box}) \qquad
U_{\Box} = U_\mu (x) U_\nu (x + \mu) U_\mu^{\dagger} (x + \nu) U_\nu^{\dagger} (x)
$$
Where $U_\mu (x)$ is the link poiniting in the $\mu$ direction from the site, located at $x$. The gauge transformations act on the links in following way:
$$
U_\mu^{'} (n) = \Omega (n) U_\mu (n) \Omega^{\dagger} (n + \mu)
$$
By an appropriate gauge transformation, any configuration can be put to so dubbed *temporal gauge* :
$$
U_0 (n) = \mathbb{1}
$$[image]

Looking at the Wilson action, one sees, that the links on different timeslices decouple from each other, and we have independent 1-dimensional spin chains, which can be interpreted as (0 + 1) dimensional field theory in Euclidean space.

Comment: Thank you! What with "quantum mechanical system of a single variable"?

Comment: @Nikita each of spin chain can be interpreted as single spin evolving in Euclidean time

Comment: How to interpretate this single spin in terms of some gauge-invariant object in gauge theory? Also it is look like that such construction work in any dimension. Why it is specific  only for 2d Maxwell theory?

Comment: @Nikita, this construction works in any dimension in sense that it reduces the gauge theory in D dimensions to a spin system in D - 1 dimensions